# Range over a slice of a struct

Tags: go

I have a struct that contains a slice of a struct and I am trying to retrieve the data from the inner struct. Here is an example of the struct:

```
type Data struct {
    Quotes []struct {
        Direct      bool    `json:"Direct"`
        Legs struct {
            ID int    `json:"Id"`
        } `json:"Legs"`
    }
}
```

From the above code I would like to retrieve the value in ID. Here is what I have tried already:

```
    for _, v := range Data.Quotes.Legs {
        fmt.Println(v.ID)
    }
```

But I get the following error:

```
 Has no field or method Legs
```

This works if I just want the value in Direct:

```
    for _, v := range Data.Quotes {
        fmt.Println(v.Direct)
    }
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Data.Quotes.Legs` is not an array. `Data.Quotes` is:

```
var data Data
...
for _, v := range data.Quotes {
        fmt.Println(v.Legs.ID)
}
```

Comment: /facepalm
Thanks very much